# Swift Xcode Error : Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linker

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFLogInViewController", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo21PFLogInViewController in ViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFSignUpViewController", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo22PFSignUpViewController in ViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo6PFUser in LoginViewController.o
  __TMaCSo6PFUser in ViewController.o
  __TMaCSo6PFUser in signUpViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo5Parse in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm having Apple Mach-O Linker Error from
1) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFLogInViewController", referenced from:
2) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFSignUpViewController", referenced from:
3) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFUser", referenced from:
4) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
5) linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can i know what is Apple Mach-O Linker Error and the way to solve this error ?

Comment: It looks like a problem with the Parse library - did you add it manually (instead of using cocoapods)? If yes, you've probably missed something

Comment: i add it by cocoapods

Comment: Did you open up the new workspace it made after the pod installed? The original project would probably do this.

Comment: And have you added [ParseUI](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ParseUI) if you're using visual parse components?

Comment: @Antonio where and how should i add the parseUI ?

Comment: @Beginner in the same way as you added the Parse lib

Comment: @Antonio i cant find the parseUI, what's the name of the UI? Cuz i cant get anything when i type in ParseUI

Comment: From now on, as the command-line warning mentioned, you must always open the workspace (.xcworkspace) and not the project (.xcodeproj). Quit Xcode and make sure you open the right one or it won't compile.

Comment: @Dare where is the workspace located ?

Comment: Usually the same folder that contains your project. I am pretty sure that's the default behavior.

Comment: @Dare i cant find the workspace but ill try

Comment: It may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685593/linker-errors-with-parseui-ios-and-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Clean build your project. Rebuild.